# How to set a div to the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This might be an extremely noobie question but I can't get anything to work. I've found a ton of questions regarding this subject but so far none of them worked. I have an application with two main containers. Basically a header and a content div. This content div needs to reach to the bottom of the page dynamically (depending on browser size).

I've tried things like height:100vw but makes the page too long and inserts a scroll bar. Also Height: 100% does nothing.

I'm using angular with bootstrap and ui.bootstrap. This is loaded into index:

```
 <div class="app-container">
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div ng-view=""></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

navbar is a custom directive that loads a template. ng-view looks like:

```
<div class="content-container">
  //content
</div>
```

so basically the content-container div needs to always reach to the bottom of the page. I've seen js solutions to this problem, but can't find any angular specific solutions.

**solution**

(thanks to Vinc199789)

```
height:calc(100vh - header_height);
```

Comment: apply this css to your content div: `height:calc(100vh - header_height);` and if you don't know the height of the header: go to webinspector en hover over the header and you propably will see the height

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the css line is crossed out on the page. Is header_height a preset or do I need to set that myself?

Comment: You have to say for example 50px or something. header_height is not a preset or a function.

Answer (score 0):

You tried with an absolute position and bottom:0px?

```
.content-conainer{
     position:absolute;
     bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: When i try this is moved the entire container to the bottom, leaving a gap between the header and the content.

Comment: Careful with the use of vh units - support is pretty poor cross browser